# How to have two differents layouts without setting one as default, or using parenting

Tags: layout, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm doing this project in order to progress in Nuxt, so I'm open to questions, tips and advice

I would like :

1. to set layout per folder so i can removed my **pages/navbar-*.vue** because i don't like the useless routes they created
   [image]

2. that my navbar-header folder doesnt affect the the path, in next, I would have set the folder between () like explained [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#organize-routes-without-affecting-the-url-path)

Is this possible in Nuxt 3 ? What are the best practices ?

Here the arch of my project. I use navbar, but it could be for another layout like Auth

```
layouts/
    navbar-header.vue 
    navbar-side.vue 

pages/
    navbar-header.vue
    navbar-side.vue
    navbar-header/ 
        index.vue
        custom-themes.vue
    navbar-side/ 
        index.vue
```

Thank you for the time you'll spend

Comment: Nuxt creates route for navbar-header or navbar-side and you don't want that? Am I right

Comment: I don't the routes _navbar-header.vue_ and _navbar-side.vue_ but only the _navbar-header/index.vue_ and _navbar-side/index.vue_
I edit the post with a picture to explain it

Answer (score 1):

You could rename your pages with hyphen `-` if you don't want Nuxt to create routes.

For-example: `navbar-header.vue` to `-navbar-header.vue`

```
layouts/
    navbar-header.vue 
    navbar-side.vue 

pages/
    -navbar-header.vue
    navbar-side.vue
    navbar-header/ 
        index.vue
        custom-themes.vue
    navbar-side/ 
        index.vue
```

Comment: If i only change the page name to ` _navbar-header.vue`, it still create the route

Comment: When your page name starts with `_` then nuxt not create a route for it. If this won't work for you try to remove `.nuxt` and `node_modules` dir and run npm i and try again

Comment: I tried and it still not working, here a playground to demonstrate https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-9rsjmw?file=pages%2Findex.vue

Comment: @BenGrandin My bad actually you don't need to use `_` before filename you need to use hyphen `-`. I update my answer you can check please.